# How to Check If an Input Field is Empty Using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

There are two fields to calculate the Pythagorean amount. The code worked well until the conditional instructions were added to the empty fields.

If the fields are empty, the message will be displayed.

HTML:

```
<p>Lengte van lijn a:</p><input id="a" type="text">
<p>Lengte van lijn b:</p><input id="b" type="text">
<button class="btn" id="PythaCal">REKENEN</button>
<P id="resPytha"></P>
```

JQ:

```
function berekenLijnC() {
    var a;
    var b;
    var c;
    a = parseFloat($("#a").val());
    b = parseFloat($("#b").val());

    if (a == "" && b == "") {
        $('#resPytha').html('u vergat alle in te vullen');
    } else if (a == "" || b == "") {
        $('#resPytha').html('u vergat iets  in te vullen');
    } else {
        c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2));
        $("#resPytha").html("lijn C is dan " + c + " cm lang");
    };
 };
 $("#PythaCal").click(berekenLijnC);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your variables `a` and `b` are `parseFloat()` this return `NaN` whenever the fields are empty or is Not A Number. So check in this case if the fields contains numbers. Change your if check to `if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {`

```js
function berekenLijnC() {
    var a;
    var b;
    var c;
    a = $("#a").val();
    b = $("#b").val();



    // Check if both of the field are empty
    if (a === "" && b === "") {
        $('#resPytha').html('Beide velden zijn leeg..');
    } else if(a === "" || b === ""){
        // Check is one of the field is empty
        $('#resPytha').html('Een van de velden is leeg..');
    } else {
        c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(parseFloat(a), 2) + Math.pow(parseFloat(b), 2));
        $("#resPytha").html("lijn C is dan " + c + " cm lang");

    };

};
$("#PythaCal").click(berekenLijnC);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lengte van lijn a:</p><input id="a" type="text">
<p>Lengte van lijn b:</p><input id="b" type="text">
<button class="btn" id="PythaCal">REKENEN</button>

<P id="resPytha"></P>
```

Comment: it works just if two fields were empty ! but it does'nt show another text error if one of fields were empty ! In any case, it displays a message for both cases.

Comment: @HMorning, than you need to change your variable, check first if any field is empty than after use `parseFloat()` i update new one

Comment: i have edited ! but not working well. expacialy for the second mode.                                                       if (a === "" || b === "") {
        $('#resPytha').html('u have to fill the both field');
    } 
        else if (a === "" && b === "") {
  $('#resultaat').html('u forgot to fill one of the fields');

 }
        
        else {
        c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(parseFloat(a), 2) + Math.pow(parseFloat(b), 2));
        $("#resPytha").html("lijn C is dan " + c + " cm lang");

Comment: @HMorning, notice that i also changed your variable for `a` and `b` remove `parseFloat()`, check my example.

Comment: Exciting that you know Dutch ! dank je wel